# Save a new Event to DB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am wanting to create a `newEvent` and add it into my event array. How do I accomplish this? I am using Mongoose to interface my DB

**Event API**

```
const newEvent = new Event({
      title: req.body.title,
      start: req.body.start,
      end: req.body.end,
      allday: req.body.allday,
      color: req.body.color,
      textcolor: req.body.textcolor,
      user: req.user.id
    });
```

**Event Schema**

```
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users"
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  events: [
    {
      title: { type: String, required: true },
      start: { type: String, required: true },
      end: { type: String, required: true },
      allday: { type: Boolean },
      color: { type: String, required: true },
      textcolor: { type: String }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const newEvent = new Event({
      events: [
        {
          title: req.body.title,
          start: req.body.start,
          end: req.body.end,
          allday: req.body.allday,
          color: req.body.color,
          textcolor: req.body.textcolor,
          user: req.user.id
        }
      ]
    });
    newEvent.save().then(event => res.json(event));
  }
);
```